# Cross compatibility with Firebase Database (iOS and Android)

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am currently using Firebase as the backend for an iOS and an Android application. The iOS application has been completed, but now when I am writing the application for Android, I am wondering how to structure the data so that it is consistent across iOS and Android?

Suppose for example:

I have a class user on the Android side that I write to the database:

```
public class User {

    public String uid;
    public String name;
    String email;
    public String gender;
    public boolean first;
    public String phone;
    public String dob;
    public String address;

    public User(String id,String nm,String em,String g,boolean f,String ph,String d,String add)
    {
        uid=id;
        name=nm;
        email=em;
        gender=g;
        first=f;
        phone=ph;
        dob=d;
        address=add;
    }
    public User()
    {

    }
}
```

Now while reading this data on the iOS side (with something like `dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)` in Android), **how do I structure the User class in iOS?**?

Similarly, what should be my approach in the opposite case (iOS to Android)?

Comment: Exactly the same? Maybe I did not understand the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to serialize Swift/Objective-C objects to the Firebase Database. You will instead have to code your own mapping between the plain-old swift object and the FIRDataSnapshot/FIRDatabaseReference.